# MYSQL join 2 tables

Tags: mysql

TABLE1

```
ID | NAME
1  | a   
2  | b  
3  | c  
4  | d
```

TABLE2

```
ID | TBL1_ID | NAME  
1  | 2       | x     
2  | 2       | y  
3  | 2       | z
```

I would like to join two tables to get all records from table 1 and all records joined from table 2 on ID

This query return only all rows from 1 table and 1 row from second table.

```
SELECT  a.*, COUNT(a.id) total FROM table1 a  
  LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.tbl1_id    
  GROUP BY a.id  
  ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * total FROM table1 a  
  left JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.tbl1_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If You need to join both tables and show all fields on matching rows this should work:

```
SELECT  * FROM table1 a  
  LEFT JOIN table2 b ON(a.id = b.tbl1_id)
```

Comment: You can't use `USING` here as the join column in the second table is `tbl1_id`.

Comment: Would it join all rows from table2?

Comment: Now I have joined all rows from table1 + first row from table2

Comment: @miojamo, It will take every row from table1 and stick it with every matching row (if exists) from table2, so in Your example the result will be: 1-a-null, 2-a-x, 2-a-y, 2-a-z, 3-c-null, 4-d-null